# Categories and Post Tags are disable when adding custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am working on a wordpress plugin. I have create a custom post type and created two user role for createing and editing the post type. But the problem is when I want to create a new post of my custom post type it shows the Category and Post Tag, but check boxes, text area inside Category and Post Tag meta boxes are disabled.

```
private function _cpCreateCustomPostType(){
    $labels = array(
            'name' => __( 'Custom Posts' ), //- general name for the post type, usually plural. The same as, and overridden by $post_type_object->label
            'singular_name' => __( 'Custom Post' ), //- name for one object of this post type. Defaults to value of name
            'menu_name' => __( 'Custom Post Menu Name' ), //- the menu name text. This string is the name to give menu items. Defaults to value of name
            'all_items' => __( 'Custom Post All Items' ), //- the all items text used in the menu. Default is the Name label
            'add_new' => __('Add New','Custom Post'), //- the add new text. The default is Add New for both hierarchical and non-hierarchical types. When internationalizing this string, please use a gettext context matching your post type. Example: _x('Add New', 'product');
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Post/Add New Page (Custom Post)' ), //- the add new item text. Default is Add New Post/Add New Page
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Post/Edit Page (Custom Post)' ),  //- the edit item text. Default is Edit Post/Edit Page
            'new_item' => __( 'New Post/New Page (Custom Post)' ), //- the new item text. Default is New Post/New Page
            'view_item' => __( 'View Post/View Page (Custom Post)' ), //- the view item text. Default is View Post/View Page
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Posts/Search Pages (Custom Post)' ), //- the search items text. Default is Search Posts/Search Pages
            'not_found' => __( 'No posts found/No pages found (Custom Post)' ), //- the not found text. Default is No posts found/No pages found
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No posts found in Trash/No pages found in Trash (Custom Post)' ), //- the not found in trash text. Default is No posts found in Trash/No pages found in Trash
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Page (Custom Post)' ) //- the parent text. This string isn't used on non-hierarchical types. In hierarchical ones the default is Parent Page
    );
    $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 15,
            'capability_type' => 'custom_post',
            'map_meta_cap' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
            'has_archive' => false
    );

    if(!post_type_exists('custom_post')){
        register_post_type('custom_post',$args);
    }
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'custom_post');
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'custom_post');
}
    private function _cpAddRoles() {
    add_role('cp_author', 'Custom Post Author', array(
    'edit_custom_posts' => true,
    'read' => true, // True allows that capability
    ));

    add_role('cp_editor', 'Custom Post Editor', array(
    'edit_custom_posts' => true,
    'read' => true, // True allows that capability
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have change your code .Please use this code..

```
add_action('init','create_custom_posttype');
function create_custom_posttype(){
             $labels = array(
                    'name' => __( 'Custom Posts' ), //- general name for the post type, usually plural. The same as, and overridden by $post_type_object->label
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Custom Post' ), //- name for one object of this post type. Defaults to value of name
                    'menu_name' => __( 'Custom Post Menu Name' ), //- the menu name text. This string is the name to give menu items. Defaults to value of name
                    'all_items' => __( 'Custom Post All Items' ), //- the all items text used in the menu. Default is the Name label
                    'add_new' => __('Add New','Custom Post'), //- the add new text. The default is Add New for both hierarchical and non-hierarchical types. When internationalizing this string, please use a gettext context matching your post type. Example: _x('Add New', 'product');
                    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Post/Add New Page (Custom Post)' ), //- the add new item text. Default is Add New Post/Add New Page
                    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Post/Edit Page (Custom Post)' ),  //- the edit item text. Default is Edit Post/Edit Page
                    'new_item' => __( 'New Post/New Page (Custom Post)' ), //- the new item text. Default is New Post/New Page
                    'view_item' => __( 'View Post/View Page (Custom Post)' ), //- the view item text. Default is View Post/View Page
                    'search_items' => __( 'Search Posts/Search Pages (Custom Post)' ), //- the search items text. Default is Search Posts/Search Pages
                    'not_found' => __( 'No posts found/No pages found (Custom Post)' ), //- the not found text. Default is No posts found/No pages found
                    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No posts found in Trash/No pages found in Trash (Custom Post)' ), //- the not found in trash text. Default is No posts found in Trash/No pages found in Trash
                    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Page (Custom Post)' ) //- the parent text. This string isn't used on non-hierarchical types. In hierarchical ones the default is Parent Page
            );
            $args = array(
                    'labels' => $labels,
                    'public' => true,
                    'menu_position' => 15,
                     'map_meta_cap' => true,
                    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments' ),
                    'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
                    'has_archive' => false
            );

            if(!post_type_exists('custom_post')){
                register_post_type('custom_post',$args);
            }

}
```

remove the   'capability_type' => 'custom_post' in your code..

Comment: Thanks @sakthi.krr

Your suggestion works. But If I remove that how I am going to use custom capabilities for my custom post type.

Thank You